# What is "blood that moved from one place to another"?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, science, lomdus, blood

I'm learning laws of salting in the Shulchan Aruch.  One concept I'm battling to understand is "דם שפירש ממקום למקום" - blood that moved from one place to another.  Here's a good example of my confusion: see [YD 69:18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=311).  The Shach in ע"ד says that blood in the flesh that did not move is permitted, but that's only "if it didn't move at all from its place".  A simple reading of this seems to imply that the Shach (and most other Rishonim and Acharonim) did not understand the concept of a circulatory system, since they seem to have a concept of a *fixed place* where each drop of blood belongs, and where it is permitted to eat it - but as soon as that blood moves out of its place, it becomes prohibited.

Perhaps the Mechaber disagrees with this interpretation of דם שפירש ממקום למקום, applying it only to blood the moved between two separate pieces of meat, or at least that exited this piece of meat and was later re-absorbed?  In the argument over whether salting is supposed to remove *all* the blood or *most of* the blood, the Rambam comes down on the latter side, which is why he requires *chalita*, to seal the blood in so that it doesn't leak out when you later cook it.  If that's the case, then he surely cannot agree with the way the Shach understands it, because whatever blood didn't come out with the salting has surely "moved" during the process - yet the Rambam permits it!

How do you understand this concept?  And if, indeed, it is based on a misconception of the circulatory system, how would the halacha be affected?

Comment: This bugs you, but you accept that Chalita "seals" the blood in?

Comment: IAE I don't really follow your problem. He's talking about Dam Eivarim not the blood in the circulatory system (which, incidentally, is hard to imagine they didn't know about; they knew about the heart). It's quite reasonable to say the the blood in the capillaries (which are tiny!) doesn't move after the heart starts pumping.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I didn't make any judgments about chalita; I'm learning about melicha now.  It's quite possible that when I get there, I'll raise another question about chalita, as you say... :)

Comment: @DoubleAA So let's assume "dam eivarim" is blood in the capillaries after the heart stops pumping.  What is the logic behind prohibiting blood that has "moved", while permitting blood that has remained stationary?  Remember, just a few minutes ago, that blood was *all* moving.  So when does the "lock" happen?  At the moment of shechita?  No way; the blood is gushing out the animal.  When the heart stops beating?  Technically, the animal was already dead the moment the simanim were cut.  So you could have already carved up the animal and started salting it before the heart stopped...

Comment: The logic in general it seems is that blood is only assur as a cheftza of blood, but not where it is batel to the meat. Once it is poresh, it attains its issur and then doesn't lose it when it is reabsorbed.

Comment: @DoubleAA You seem to be defining "poresh" as leaving the piece of meat altogether.  The Shach is defining "poresh" as one drop of blood moving one millimeter within a capillary.

Comment: I haven't learned the laws of Melicha in a while, but isn't the idea that the blood has moved from place to place __by an outside force__?

Comment: @Menachem Sounds like an interesting theory.  Do you have any citations to back it up?

Comment: @Shaul: Not sure, but look at the Aruch HaShulchan 67:7, who defines "blood that has not separated" as blood that has not been "awakened to move", perhaps indicating an outside force is needed. - http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A1.D7.96_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96  -- he also finishes off by saying that raw, unsalted meat must be de-veined before eating.

Comment: some sources: http://dafyomi.co.il/menachos/halachah/mn-hl-100.htm

Comment: @Menachem I believe you are right.  See the Tur on YD 67.  Please post as an answer for credit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [here](http://dafyomi.co.il/menachos/halachah/mn-hl-100.htm) for an evolution of the different opinions in Halacha regarding blood that moved, and eating raw meat (from the Talmud to the Poskim).

"blood that moved" is talking about the blood that is found in the meat, not the veins/arteries (as [the Tur (67)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14267&pgnum=205) and [others](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A1.D7.96_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96) say, while raw meat may be permitted without salting, the blood found in the veins/arteries are forbidden).

The language used by the Tur (and others), "שנתעורר לצאת‏" - That was awakened to move -,  seems to indicate that it is only called "blood that moved" if it was caused to move by an outside source.

There are opinions that it is only called 'blood that moved' if it left the meat and was later reabsorbed, but I don't think we rule that way halachically.

See [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25421&pgnum=62) for a discussion of this concept as well, by HaRav Avraham Wilhelm (I didn't read the whole thing but he brings and discusses the different opinions)

Comment: Per science, blood is always in the circulatory system, just in narrow and narrower tubes.

Comment: Since the question is specifically about science, I'm going to press you further. What do you mean veins? Is that to exclude arteries? If so, why? If not, then wouldn't all capillaries fit in as well? Blood is always in a vein, artery or capillarity (when not inside the heart/lungs/liver/kidney). What does 'in the meat' mean scientifically?

Comment: @DoubleAA: The term the Tur uses is 'the strings that have blood in them, since the blood in the strings are as if gathered and standing in a vessel'. If I had to guess, I'd say that all the tubes (veins, arteries) that are still recognizable as such are forbidden, but ones that do not have recognizable tubes are permitted. According to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary the walls of the capillaries are just one cell thick. Hardly recognizable as tubes.

Comment: For the record, the Rosh defines "blood that moved" specifically as having left the meat altogether; he seems to be your primary source for your paragraph beginning "There are opinions..."